# Generate element from submit React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, submit

I'd like to generate some HTML to show sucessfull form submission. I can't seem to do it within the `handleSubmit` Method.

```
class BookingForm extends Component{
...


handleChange(event) {
 const target = event.target;
 const value = target.value;
 const name = target.name;
 console.log(name + ' '+value);
 this.setState({
  [name]: value
 });
}
```

Submit method that I'd like to render `html`:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
console.log(this.state.lessonTime)
event.preventDefault();
this.setState({'success':true})
return(
  <h1>Success</h1>
);

}

render() {
return (
  <div>
  <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <TimeList defaultTime={this.state.defaultTime}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
  <br/>
  <DateList defaultDate={this.state.defaultDate}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
  <br/>
  <NumberOfLessons defaultNOL={this.state.defaultLessons}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
  <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Book Lesson" />
  </form>
  <br/>

  </div>

);
}
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the success heading to show once submit has been clicked on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a better way to handle this is to use state to control the rendering of "success" heading. You can add the following line of code to the place you want to add the header:

```
{this.state.success && <div> Successful </div> }
```

I think the reason the html tag returned by `handleSubmit` in your function doesn't show up is because although it returns the tag, it doesn't know where to put it. If you want to make it work, you'll need to use methods like `createElement` and `appendChild` but that's not the way react should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `<h1>` element to render instead of form on successful completion do this in your render function:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
   {this.state.success?(
    <h1>Success</h1>
   ):(
   <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
   <TimeList defaultTime={this.state.defaultTime}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
  <br/>
  <DateList defaultDate={this.state.defaultDate}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
  <br/>
  <NumberOfLessons defaultNOL={this.state.defaultLessons}
            handleChange={this.handleChange}/>
  <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Book Lesson" />
  </form>
  <br/>)}
  </div>
);
}
```